# Python import modules solution for scripts

Tags: python, import, pycharm, python-venv

My project structure looks like

--src/core

--src/bin

i have a bunch of scripts that i want to run from bin that import from src/core

when i run them from PyCharms everything works fine.

when i run the same script from my terminal, i get ModuleNotFound error

the difference is in the PYTHONPATH (Pycharm adds the root directory at runtime - venv does not)

my current hack is to add this to all my scripts that i want to call

```
import sys, os
root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../.."))
sys.path.append(root_path)
```

what is a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your project a package, run it with a runner script or with `python -m my_app`, and have access to relative imports (`from . import foo`), as well as package-based ones (`from my_app import foo`)

Comment: i didnt follow this.. say my executable is src/bin/runscript.py

right now i am trying `python src/bin/runScript.py`

now i should try `python -m src/bin/runScript`?

Comment: @Shubham The invocation would look like `python -m src.bin.runScript`. This would require and `__init__.py` in `src` and `src/bin/`. Inside the script you would then have `from src.core import stuff`